# What movie is this that showed up unexpectedly instead of an internet advertisement?

Tags: story-identification, movie, actor-identification

I was watching short videos on a normal news website, and instead of showing a normal 30 second commercial it unexpectedly started playing a 1 hour (72 minutes I think) SciFi movie! The whole time it shows Advertisement at the bottom, but I just left the controls alone for fear they might interrupt viewing.

There was a normal feature length movie introduction giving names of actors but I didn't pay attention at that point. Later I discovered I couldn't back up and check them.

All I have are screen shots. I've cropped out the video player parts and collected some together, shown below. Perhaps this will help identify one of the actors, which would then help for title look-up. Japanese is spoken during some "bad guy" scenes.

Does this jog anybody's memory? I'd like to look up the film and find the actor and production credits.

The story starts with a guy having a nightmare, his "uncle" giving him a tranquilizer, going to high-school the next day, then a SWAT-like team enters the classroom and tries to take him into custody. He has unusual "powers" and escapes.

**Question:** What is the title of the film, how can I look up the actor and production credits? Any idea why this would have been shown to me randomly for free? (I'm browsing from Taiwan and advertisements are usually targeted to local viewers.)

---

Here is what was shown at the top of the screen. There's not much to go on; I've tried to sharpen but it's still difficult to read. It doesn't appear to name the movie though...

[image: Text at the top of the screen]

[image: Collage of various screenshots from the movie]

Comment: That is weird. Maybe advertisers were using Youtube to host their ads, and somebody "fat-fingered" one of the URLs. I know this: all I ever get is the same pharmaceutical ad over and over, never "Deadpool 2"...

Comment: @Harper - Youtube paid your doctor to share your medical records... You need those pills and once you buy some you will be rewarded with a Deadpool 2 trailer; just one, so don't blink...

Comment: I've seen another movie this way, quite by accident. The odd part is, it was a movie I liked, which makes me wonder if YouTube/Google was smart enough to realize that I would like to see the movie based on my tastes... which makes me wonder why there isn't an app that recommends new stuff that I might like...

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This appears to be [Kill Order](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt3847642/), a 2017 movie starring Chris Mark.

In the trailer, you can see a number of the points you describe, including waking up from a nightmare and a SWAT team coming for him while he's in class:

Comment: For the record, never seen the movie, but I found it through the text from the top of the screen you provided... I couldn't actually read the username itself, but I searched for the 'to watch more movies with best quality' hoping the idiosyncratic English would lead me to other uses of the same phrase and it did, once I found the youtube, just a bit of browsing located the full movie in question, though the video name was different from the movie name.

Comment: No idea why it would have been sent, my guess is maybe the ad provided the youtube video code of an actual ad they wanted to run and it was one character mistyped and happened to get that full movie hosted (and likely illegally so) on this random person's youtube page.

Comment: That was fast! Yes indeed this is it. About searching; there is a common misconception that searching the internet from one country is representative of what search results will look like elsewhere, but this just isn't always case. Keywords that work well in some locations may be unsuccessful in another. (see the last sentence in [this question](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/27339/12102) and comments below it for example)